# How to center boxes on top of lines in the legend of a plot?

Tags: r, plot, legend

I would like to superimpose transparent boxes on top of the lines in the legend.

A small example:

```
xdata <- 1:7
y1 <- c(1,4,9,16,25,36,49)
y2 <- c(1, 5, 12, 21, 34, 51, 72)
y3 <- c(1, 6, 14, 28, 47, 73, 106 )
y4 <- c(1, 7, 17, 35, 60, 95, 140 )

plot(xdata, y1, type = 'l', col = "red")
lines(xdata, y2, type = 'l', col = "red", lty = 3)
lines(xdata, y3, type = 'l', col = "blue") 
lines(xdata, y4, type = 'l', col = "blue",  lty = 3)

# add legend with lines
legend("topleft", legend = c("Plot 1", "Plot 2", "Plot 3", "Plot 4"),
      lty = c(1,3,1,3), lwd = rep(1.3 ,4),
      col = c("blue", "blue", "red", "red") ,
      pch = rep(NA, 4), cex = 0.8, 
      x.intersp = 0.7, y.intersp = 1.2, bty = 'n')

# add boxes
legend("topleft", legend = c("", "", "", ""), lty = rep(0, 4), 
       col = c(adjustcolor(blues9[3], alpha.f = 0.6), 
               adjustcolor(blues9[3], alpha.f = 0.6), 
               adjustcolor("red", alpha.f = 0.1), 
               adjustcolor("red", alpha.f = 0.1)),
        pch = rep(15, 4), cex = 0.8, pt.cex = rep(2, 4),
        x.intersp = 0.7, y.intersp = 1.2, bty = 'n')
```

which produces:

[image]

As you can see, the boxes are shifted to the left along the lines in the legend.

How can I set the alignment of the boxes, so that they become horizontally centered on top of the line symbols in the legend?  Thanks!

Comment: Is it important that the graph be made using base graphics? Or would something else (ggplot, lattice etc.) be ok?

Comment: Preferably I would like base graphics as I am currently dealing with multiple graphs with these types of parameters. However, any suggestions to doing it with ggplot, etc would also be welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The clue here is to specify the same `lwd` in both `legend` calls, i.e. also in the call for the boxes where `lty = 0`.

Here's a simpler example, with only the arguments relevant for your actual issue:

```
plot(1)

# lines
legend(x = "topleft",
       legend = c("Plot 1", "Plot 2", "Plot 3", "Plot 4"), bty = 'n',
       lty = c(1, 3), lwd = 1,
       pch = NA,
       col = rep(c("blue", "red"), each = 2))

# boxes
legend(x = "topleft", 
       legend = rep("", 4), bty = "n",
       lty = 0, lwd = 1, # <- lwd = 1  
       pch = 15, pt.cex = 2,
       col = c(rep(adjustcolor(blues9[3], alpha.f = 0.6), 2),
               rep(adjustcolor("red", alpha.f = 0.1), 2)))
```

[image]

---

If you're fine with a coloured outline of the boxes, one `legend` call is enough. Just use a `pch` which accepts `pt.bg` (here: 22):

```
plot(1)
legend(x = "topleft",
       legend = c("Plot 1", "Plot 2", "Plot 3", "Plot 4"), bty = 'n',
       lty = c(1, 3), col = rep(c("blue", "red"), each = 2),
       pch = 22, pt.cex = 2, 
       pt.bg = c(rep(adjustcolor(blues9[3], alpha.f = 0.6), 2),
                 rep(adjustcolor("red", alpha.f = 0.1), 2)))
```

[image]

Comment: @user321627 I note that you didn't place your 200 bounty, neither accepted any answer (which is fine - neither is required). Still, I'm curious what (if anything) was wrong with the answers provided?

Answer (score 8):

Since you explicitly welcome alternative solutions, here is a possibility using `ggplot2`

```
library(tidyverse);
data.frame(xdata, y1, y2, y3, y4) %>%
    gather(key, y, -xdata) %>%
    mutate(key = sub("y", "Plot ", key)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(xdata, y, colour = key, linetype = key)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = y, ymax = y, fill = key), alpha = 0.2, colour = NA) +
    scale_colour_manual(
        values = c("Plot 1" = "red", "Plot 2" = "red", "Plot 3" = "blue", "Plot 4" = "blue"),
        name = "Legend") +
    scale_linetype_manual(
        values = c("Plot 1" = "solid", "Plot 2" = "dashed", "Plot 3" = "solid", "Plot 4" = "dashed"),
        name = "Legend") +
    scale_fill_manual(
        values = c("Plot 1" = "red", "Plot 2" = "red", "Plot 3" = "blue", "Plot 4" = "blue"),
        name = "Legend") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.justification = c(0, 1),
        legend.position = c(0.02, 0.98),
        legend.spacing.x = unit(0.5, 'cm'),
        legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

Here is a summary of the key adjustments:

1. Add a `fill` aesthetic through a zero width `geom_ribbon`. This will give us the coloured boxes in the legend. We use `alpha = 0.2` to ensure transparency.
2. We manually give all aesthetic scales the same name. This prevents three different legends, and combines `colour`, `linetype`, and `fill` in one single legend.
3. We tweak the legend position through

   - `legend.position` and `legend.justification` to make sure the legend is within the plot region in the top-left corner. These parameters require a bit of fine-tuning depending on the legend text,
   - removing the legend title with `legend.title = element_blank()`,
   - increasing the distance between legend symbol and text with `legend.spacing.x`; again this parameter may require a bit of manual fine-tuning depending on your personal preference.

Lastly, we do some minor adjustments to increase aesthetic similarity with the base R plot, by removing grid lines (`theme_bw` in combination with `panel.grid.major = element_blank()` and `panel.grid.minor = element_blank()`).

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I have done using **base R:**

Below are some of the settings which you can do at your end to get the desired result.

`seg.len` : It basically works with length of the legend line in the base R plotting graphics, I have taken this values as 1.25

`pt.cex` : rep(4.4,4), so we have taken box as squares, I have adjusted the value of thse squares using 4.4

`x.intersp` : It deals between the space between text of the legend and the legend shape

`text.col` : This is an optional setting for the colour of the text of the legend if you comment it , You will get legend text it as black (like your answer)

`xjust`: for the value of 0 the legend  is left justified , for 0,5 it is centre justified and for 1 it is right justified

I have changed these settings iteratively to came with these as final result. I am hopeful that would be helpful to you. I have run this many times on machine to come up with this.

Above all the settings I have played with and came up with the below chart:

```
plot(xdata, y1, type = 'l', col = "red")
lines(xdata, y2, type = 'l', col = "red", lty = 3)
lines(xdata, y3, type = 'l', col = "blue") 
lines(xdata, y4, type = 'l', col = "blue",  lty = 3)
legend("topleft", legend = c("Plot 1", "Plot 2", "Plot 3", "Plot 4"), 
       lty = c(1,3,1,3), lwd = rep(1.3 ,4), 
       col = c("blue", "blue", "red", "red") , 
       pch = rep(NA,4), cex = 0.8, 
       text.col = c("blue", "blue", "red","red"),
       y.intersp=1.2, bty = 'n', x.intersp = .5,
       seg.len = 1.265, xjust =1)
legend("topleft", legend = c("", "", "", ""), lty = rep(0, 4),
       col = c(adjustcolor(blues9[3],alpha.f=0.6),
               adjustcolor(blues9[3],alpha.f=0.6),
               adjustcolor("red",alpha.f=0.1),
               adjustcolor("red",alpha.f=0.1)),
       pch = rep(15,4), bty ='n', cex = 0.8,
       pt.cex = rep(4.3, 4), y.intersp = 1.2, x.intersp =  0.1,
       xjust = 0)
```

[image]

**Note:** *You have zoom the graph to see the correct effect in R Studio.*